# Iteration in javascript only returns the first element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippet

```js
$("#personalizacoesOpcionais")
      .find(".qtdPersonalizacao")
      .each(function (n, t) {
         var i = {};
         i.IdProdutoIngrediente = parseInt($(t).attr("data-id"));
         i.Qtde = parseFloat($(t).text());            
         r[n] = i
       });
```

In the html there are several divs `personalizacoesOpcionais` and each one with numerous elements `qtdPersonalizacao`.
However, the code snippet above only returns the first item `qtdPersonalizacao` within the first `personalizacoesOpcionais`.

Comment: I assume that is jQuery?

Comment: This is jQuery iteration, not pure JS.

Comment: If there are several divs with the id of `personalizacoesOpcionais`, no wonder why it does not return more than one since ids are UNIQUE

Comment: @epascarello exactly

Comment: what is `r` ( from `r[n] = i` ) ?

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for paying attention to this detail. I had the problem due to an error in the placement of divs. Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, the code snippet above only returns the first item qtdPersonalizacao within the first personalizacoesOpcionais.

Ids are supposed to be unique within a document and jQuery will just returns the first matching element.

The recommended solution would be to use a class instead of an id for `personalizacoesOpcionais`.

If this is not possible, for example if you don't control the code that generate the markup, a workaround would be to use `$("div[id=personalizacoesOpcionais]")` instead of `$("#personalizacoesOpcionais")`

Comment: Thank you for paying attention to this detail. I had the problem due to an error in the placement of divs. Worked perfectly!